# set width for <a element in <td to 100%

Tags: html

is there any way to set the link element `<a` to 100% width inside a `<td` ???

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A link `<a>` is inline element, you can't apply a width to it unless you make it block-level element:

```
#tableID td a{
   display:inline-block;
   width:100%;
}
```

The above selector will make all links inside `td` inside table with id `#tableID` block so that `width` is applicable.

[Check out Inline and Block elements for more info](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/)

Answer (score 2):

Give the `<a>` element `display: block;` and it will gain the full width of its parent.

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sUT5e/**